# The Page 404 not working with .htaccess?

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

i have this Code in my .htaccess file:

```
#Rewrite everything to https
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]




RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,QSA,NC,L]


RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?witz=$1 [L,QSA]


ErrorDocument 404 https://example.com/erorrpage.php

ErrorDocument 403 https://example.com/erorrpage.php
```

i have one argument like this:

https://example.com/var

Comment: so what is it you're wanting to do? Store var as a witz get param?

Comment: Please add Errordocoment on your top of the file and then put other code. It will work.

Comment: i need The Page 404 working ! but is does not work

Comment: Darshan Jain , Also is not working

Comment: Could it be a typo? `erorrpage.php`

Comment: a top also not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ErrorDocument` is not getting triggered because of the following Rule you have in your htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ index.php?witz=$1 [L,QSA]
```

The Rule redirects everything that doesn't exist as directory `!-d` and `!-f` file to `/index.php` . Since `mod-rewrite` Rules are applied before `mod-core`  your  ErrorDocument will never get applied.

To solve this,You need to use a `mod-rewrite` Rule instead of ErrorDocument to Redirect non-existent requests to 404 page. So put the following at the top of your `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ - [R=404,L]
```

If you want to redirect 404 requests to a specific page ,you can use the following

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /errorpage.php [R= 404,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I will suppose that you use apache.

1. Ensure that your .htaccess file are on the right directory (like root directory for example) or `erorrpage.php` is accessible on the `https://example.com/`
2. Try to simplify it with `ErrorDocument 404 "Custom very simple 404 error"`, just to see if it works
3. Ensure that your mod rewrite is enabled (on `httpd.conf`, uncomment the `;LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` if not. Then restart apache)
4. Find the relevant directory tag for your www root (on other words, on your apache config of your root directory) and change `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All`
5. If the problem occured in a web hosting, the ensure that it allow the .htaccess
6. If all of these does not work, try to check [apache official docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#errordocument)

Comment: it was working befor this:
index.php?witz=$1
after i added this argumint not working 404